# Welcome someone who returned to their home country

Tags: prepositions

I wanted to say "Welcome back to your home country!" but I'm not sure if this is correct. Should I say "in" instead of "to" or is there a better way of saying this?

Comment: **Return back** is redundant! *Welcome back to your home country!* is good.

Comment: If I were the concerned person, I would feel happy if someone had welcomed me by saying "Welcome back to your country". I don't think the word 'Home' is required here. The fact that you are mentioning 'your' should do the rest of the work. That's a personal thought.

Comment: 'Welcome home' seems the most idiomatic.

Comment: Definitely not "in" - "to" is the correct word. Unless it's significant that their "home" (as opposed to their "home country") is somewhere else, just "Welcome home!" is the right phrase. If you do want to separate "home" from "home country" then something like "xx welcomes you back!" could do it where xx is the country.

Comment: Agree with @EdwinAshworth. I would simply say "Welcome Home!" as a native English (USA) speaker. This is what you would most often see on a banner, say, when a soldier returns from an oversees deployment, for example. But there's nothing incorrect grammatically with "Welcome back to your home country!" to answer your question.

Comment: If the country concerned has a nickname then "Welcome back to..." is just fine. For example saying to a British person returning home "Welcome back to good old Blighty" would be perfectly OK if a little archaic these days.

Comment: great input from everyone, thank you!
@PCurd I liked your comment the most so far, so if you'd post it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: However you say it, they will appreciate it. *Welcome!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not "in" - "to" is the correct word. Unless it's significant that their "home" (as opposed to their "home country") is somewhere else, just "Welcome home!" is the right phrase. If you do want to separate "home" from "home country" then something like "xx welcomes you back!" could do it where xx is the country.